# In plesk how do I give the user the privileges to create databases using php, but in his domain only

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, plesk

On our server we have many domains and we use plesk 12.5.30. On one domain I want to give the user the means to create his own databases in that domain only in php. This isn't the question, but I created the first database for the user and set up the username and password for that database. So the user could log into that database but he did not have permission to create new databases in php, so this is what I did.

In plesk I went to the global phpmyadmin(as the local one to that domain has not got the privileges option), and not the local one for that domain and I gave the user the privilege to create databases, but there is a problem. When he creates a database it does not show up in his domain, but it shows up in the root. You can see the database in the global phpmyadmin, but not the local one, and also plesk cannot see it. Worst than this, now the user has access to every database on the server.

My question is this. In plesk how do I give the user the privileges to create databases using php, but in his domain only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Plesk customer's user has access to API-RPC and there is possible to create DB via API-RPC call from PHP code:

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/managing-databases/creating-databases.34407/#o34418

You just need to tell to customer his webspace(subscription) id(and if need DB server id):

```
<?php

require_once('PleskApiClient.php'); // You can download it by link below

$host = '127.0.0.1'; // It's your Plesk server IP
$login = 'client_login'; // it's your client login name
$password = 's$cr3t'; // Client's password
$client = new PleskApiClient($host); // Init Plesk client
$client->setCredentials($login, $password); 

$webspaceId = 7; // webspace/subscription Id where customer wants to create database
$dbName = 'MyNewDataBase'; // name of new database

$request = <<<EOF
<packet>
<database>

<add-db>
   <webspace-id>$webspaceId</webspace-id>
   <name>$dbName</name>
   <type>mysql</type>
</add-db>

</database>
</packet>
EOF;

$response = $client->request($request); // Send query to Plesk host
echo $response; // show response

// parse new database id from $response to variable $dbId

// assign existed DB user to new database
$requestToAssignDefaultUser = <<<EOF
<packet>
<database>
   <set-default-user>
      <db-id>$dbId</db-id>
      <default-user-id>35</default-user-id>
   </set-default-user>
</database>
</packet>
EOF;

$response = $client->request($requestToAssignDefaultUser); // Send query to Plesk host
echo $response; // show response
```

You can get subscription/webspace id by another API request or from UI:

[image: Plesk database create from API]

You can find Plesk API PHP client and usage example here: https://github.com/plesk/api-examples/tree/master/php

Comment: This is all new to me. Just to clarify do you mean instead of creating the database using CREATE DATABASE and then adding the tables using CREATE TABLE that instead that I use php to remote control plesk and get plesk to do the work. Is this what you are saying? I have to admit I am having trouble understanding this rpc code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And it's a most easy, safe and idiomatic way. I've add example in PHP. Approach you suggest has issue because Plesk will not see such new databases and can't backup or manage them.

Comment: Will try this later, and let you know if it worked. The only thing I am unsure about is the $webspaceid. I know the url, password, and loginname though. ps had already downloaded the api, but couldn't get it to work. I hope your new code works.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but I am having a problem. I have now found my webspace id, but when I run the script it keeps saying  error 1001 You have entered incorrect username or password. I know my user name and password is correct because it is the same as the ftp one. I even tried the database username and password. This is why I have been taking a long time. I have checked and rechecked.

Comment: Thought I should say I am using the webhost username and password. Is this the correct one to use?

Comment: You should use login and password of Plesk customer.

Comment: Btw, you can install "XML-RPC API Explorer" extension from UI to play with Plesk API.

Comment: Thanks I know I am not supposed to thank but I got it to work with your help. Basically once I created a customer and subscription it worked. I was just trying to do it with a web host only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121477/discussion-between-thomas-williams-and-oleg-neumyvakin).

Comment: There is two small problems with the added database. First of all even though it shows up under my domain correctly, the database is not assigned to the site. Also it is not assigned to a user or default user. I have been reading through the plesk api manual, but haven't found the answer yet, as it isn't laid out very well.

Comment: You can assign DB user to new database by another request https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/managing-databases/assigning-default-database-users.34441/#o34453

Comment: I finally created the database, and got the id back from the response by using preg_replace. Then I used that id to create another packet to create the user name. Then I realised that I didn't need to do this. If in plesk I set the user to ANY then any new database will use that user.